# JBC soldering iron cartridge thermocouple type

Tags: soldering, thermocouple, soldering-iron-station

I have recently bought a T245-B soldering iron handle and a C245064 cartridge. These are both made by JBC. I have tried to find the thermocouple type online but have had a range of answers from type k to j and n. I know for a fact that the voltage drop is proportional to a type k up until 100C.

Does anyone definitely know which type of thermocouple is used in their cartridges?